# How to provide tenants in SaaS application with their @companyName.application.com specific email services?

Tags: email, smtp, saas, multi-tenant

In our SaaS application each company (tenant) is given their custom domain like **companyName.ourapp.com**
We would like to provide some email services like:

- Ability to send and receive email notifications from info@companyName.ourapp.com and similar addresses
- Ability to create new email accounts in clients' subdamains at runtime, programmatically, when needed. For example we would have separate emails created for each "opening" so that emails sent to this address would be parsed info would be extracted
- Similar tasks

For now I just don't even know on where to look and how this could possibly work.
As far as I understand email it should be some kind of custom mail server (SMTP) serving all sub-domains and having API we can use to send emails, list and retrieve messages etc.

Please suggest how it may work and is there any components out there we can use to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options for this.

- Create an email server and programatically configure it to accept or deny the specific accounts. Then use cron to poll via pop3 or imap and download the messages for the account. You can then send them on for the customer or handle them in your web app.
- Create a script that is fired by the email server as it receives each email. The script can then handle what to do with the email as it's received.
- Use a third party to receive the email via HTTP Post at your app. Using [CloudMailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com) for example would allow you to create a custom authorization filter that would call your app in realtime and determine if the given account exists and messages should be accepted for it.

I wrote a [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/) for Rails about receiving incoming email, however the principals would apply to any programming language and framework.